# Jquery change event does not work

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker and multiple textboxes.

If i change **datetimepicker date** , i want to apply date to "**all textbox values**"

However, if i change datetinepicker date , it changes but textbox values never change.

Where i miss ?

**My Code:**

```
$("#requestDateChange").change(function(){


$("#orderList").find("tbody tr").each(function(){
$("#requestDate"+ $(this).data("productid")).val($("#requestDateChange").val());

    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Share your html also ..

Comment: have you stepped through the code in dev tools? is the .change() method actually being fired?

Comment: any fiddle of your code?

Comment: may be this will help http://jsfiddle.net/UKaAx/

Comment: You code should work as-is, so it may well be down to something you are not showing. Please show an example of your table HTML etc and *all* your relevant code.

Comment: -1: Without the HTML this cannot easily be diagnosed making the question "unclear". *If* the required HTML is added I will remove the down-vote :)

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
$(document).on('change','#requestDateChange',function(){
      $("#orderList").find("tbody tr").each(function(){
      $("#requestDate"+ $(this).data("productid")).val($("#requestDateChange").val());    
  });
});
```

Comment: If you are going to simply change from a standard `change` event to a delegated version of `on` please explain why to them :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) option

```
$('#requestDateChange').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (date) {
        $("#requestDate"+ $(this).data("productid")).val(date);
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Xz83V/)

Answer (score 0):

FocusOut solved the problem.
Thanks to everyone.